# Sqlite Join confusion

Tags: sqlite

My first ever Stackoverflow question so go easy on me, I am not very experienced with SQLite.

I have a table of football teams

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    teamId      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name        TEXT,
    );
```

and a table of matches

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
        matchId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        homeTeamId  INTEGER,
        awayTeamId  INTEGER,
        );
```

I am trying to work out the SELECT statement that would display the list of matches but would replace both the homeTeamId and the awayTeamId numbers with the team names.

I have tried several variants but because two fields in the matches table join back to the same teams table I am getting either syntax errors or ambiguous column errors.

Sorry for a fairly basic question, any help appreciated.

Geoff

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select m.matchId, h.name, a.name 
from matches m
inner join teams h on h.teamId = m.homeTeamId
inner join teams a on a.teamId = m.awayTeamId
```

You have not posted the variants you have tried, so I just assume that you the problem was caused by not using aliases (in my example `h` and `a`) for the table `teams`. You have to use at least one alias, if you need to join one table twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the speedy reply. In the typical way I stumbled on the solution about 15 minutes after I posted my question, my solution was identical to yours except that I didn't bother aliasing the matches table.

Your answer had a little typo in it I think

```
SELECT m.matchId, h.name, a.name 
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN teams h ON h.teamId = m.homeTeamId
INNER JOIN teams a ON a.teamId = a.awayTeamId
                              -- ^ should be m.awayTeamId
```

But thanks again for your help!

Geoff